# Naming Angular modules

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to clean up my Angular app a little bit and when I came to my `app.js.coffee` file I ran into some things I have little knowledge of because I copy/pasted it from another source and it seemed to work.

To my knowledge every controller, service, filter etc. needs a ,

```
angular.module('nameOfModule')
```

But 2 (or more) controllers can't have the same module name because then Angular outputs an error,

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'nameOfModule' is not a function, got undefined
```

But it seems the module name that you give a controller such as `nameOfModule` can be used on multiple services,

addMovieService.js

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movieAdd',
```

movieSearchService.js

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('MovieSearch',
```

So I'm starting to wonder what the module names are for.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency for your angular module and if not then put it blank like this

```
angular.module('nameOfModule',[])
```

Error is occured because you don't add dependency for your module.

Comment: additional, calling `angular.module` without depency will give back the module :)

Answer (score 0):

> But 2 (or more) controllers can't have the same module name

**This assumption is incorrect!** Modules almost always have more than one controllers. In fact it is the highest level in an angular app and the module, along with all other entities (controllers, services, factories) comprise of a self sustaining AngularJS app.

For using another app inside another app, you just include the module as a dependancy like this:

```
angular.module('secondApp', ['firstApp'])
```

Comment: Could you explain the relationship between module names injected in the angular app config and the names of the controllers, services etc?

Comment: There is no relationship between their 'names'. You can use whatever name that feels right.